# Sending messages from parent app to WatchKit Interface

Tags: ios, iphone, ipc, watchkit

I can send a message from my WatchKit Interface to its parent application using `+openParentApplication:reply:`, and I can provide data from the parent application in the reply.

Is there an official Apple mechanism for triggering a message in the other direction, ideally an Objective-C API with similar support for arbitrary user data, or do I have to use a library like [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `openParentApplication:reply:` does have that `reply` parameter for sending a message back to the WatchKit side.

But I think you mean triggering a message from the iPhone app directly. You can look into [Darwin notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html) for this. It's a C API, but the concepts are similar to NSNotificationCenter where you register to listen for certain notifications, and then post notifications from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good thing to know about. Ideally I'd like to use an Objective-C API. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: MMWormhole makes Darwin notifications a lot easier: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Comment: I ended up using MMWormhole, it's definitely a huge help.